# React clone and appendchild

Tags: reactjs

I'm using this:

```
    const scroll_div = document.querySelector('.cryptobar_wrapper');
    const items_wrapper = scroll_div.querySelector('.items_wrapper');

    const htmlNode = document.createElement("div");
    const items_wrapper_2 = React.cloneElement(items_wrapper);
    console.log(items_wrapper_2)
    htmlNode.innerHTML = renderToString(items_wrapper_2);
    scroll_div.appendChild(htmlNode.firstChild);
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div className={'cryptobar_wrapper'}>

        <div className={'items_wrapper'}>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={btc_icon} alt={'btc_icon'}/>
                <p>{btc_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={cardano_icon} alt={'cardano_icon'}/>
                <p>{cardan_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={dogecoin_Logo} alt={'dogecoin_icon'}/>
                <p>{dogecoin_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={eth_icon} alt={'eth_icon'}/>
                <p>{eth_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={bnb_icon} alt={'bnb_icon'}/>
                <p>{bnb_price} $</p>
            </div>

            <div className={'cryptobar_item'}>
                <img src={bnb_icon} alt={'bnb_icon'}/>
                <p>{bnb_price} $</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

the values:

```
const [btc_price, set_btc_price] = useState(0)
const [cardan_price, set_cardan_price] = useState(0)
const [dogecoin_price, set_dogecoin_price] = useState(0)
const [eth_price, set_eth_price] = useState(0)
const [bnb_price, set_bnb_price] = useState(0)
```

Link to repo: https://github.com/kadiemq/tradingcompanionfrontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **It's because your `items_wrapper_2` is a `ReactNode`, not an `HTMLNode`**

So you will need to turn your `items_wrapper_2` into an actual HTMLNode before using `appendChild` function:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

// Create a fake htmlNode
const htmlNode = document.createElement("div");

// Do actual React.clone
const items_wrapper_2 = React.cloneElement(items_wrapper);

// Render "items_wrapper_2" to string and set innerHTML
htmlNode.innerHTML = renderToString(items_wrapper_2);

// Appending to "scroll_div" with firstChild to ignore initial div wrapper
scroll_div.appendChild(htmlNode.firstChild);
```

---

### **UPDATE:**

After discussing with the author, understand more on his issue, here is an update to his issue:

In your case, both `React.cloneElement` and `HTML.cloneNode` can't work, this is because Reactjs will lost track from your newly created nodes.

My suggested solution is to have a counting state like so:

```
const [rounds, setRounds] = useState(1);
```

Then render your tree:

```
{[...Array(rounds)].map((round) => (
        <div key={round} className={'items_wrapper'}>
...the rest
```

Within `move()` function, you will increase rounds by one:

```
function move() {
    const scroll_div = document.querySelector('.cryptobar_wrapper');
    const items_wrapper = scroll_div.firstChild;
    setRounds(rounds + 1);
```

Then your infinite scroll will keep render new items:
[image]

Comment: Thank you and I think you meant `const htmlObject` instead of `const htmlNode` anyway I did that and now I'm getting this error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined`

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. I updated it. In which line did you get that error?

Comment: I got it in this line: `htmlNode.innerHTML = renderToString(items_wrapper_2);`

Comment: Is your items_wrapper_2 a react component? Could you log to verify it?

Comment: This is what I get `{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: undefined, key: undefined, ref: undefined, props: {…}, …}` when I `console.log(items_wrapper_2)`

Comment: What is in your items_wrapper then? Its super helpful if you could provide more context to the question. I’ll try to find the root cause.

Comment: I added more data to my question.

Comment: Now, I get really confused. Why don't you keep using `cloneNode` but move to `React.cloneElement`? I didn't know `items_wrapper` is actually an HTMLNode

Comment: when I use `cloneNode` the elements does not update, for example `{btc_price}` in the original element do update its value but in the cloned element it does not it stays 0

Comment: I see, Do you have a full repo so I can take a look better at it?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/kadiemq/tradingcompanionfrontend

Comment: Thanks. I’ll take a look tmr. Its night time at my side.

Comment: Hey dude, I created a PR for your repo with my implementation, you could consider merging it or take the idea and implement it yourself.

Comment: Here is the link to my PR: https://github.com/kadiemq/tradingcompanionfrontend/pull/1/files

Sorry about formatting your file. Your file is relatively the same with my minor changes.